# Gay person seeking asylum from Pakistan

Tags: pakistani-citizen, asylum

I am 21 years old, living currently in Lahore, Pakistan, born here with the same nationality. I am gay. Pakistan is an Islamic state, and I fear that I cannot live my life as a gay person, or even as a gay person who chooses not to engage in gay relationships, etc. in Pakistan, as being gay is illegal and there are no special rights for LGBT people, like in the UK. Being gay, I would not want to marry a woman and have children in Pakistan.

I tried to move to the UK, but my study visa was rejected due to a non-genuine bank statement. I received an automatic refusal for 10 years.

Having this refusal, it would be extremely hard to move to countries which share information with the UK, such as the US, Canada, Australia, and there are embassy interviews for European countries. I cannot move to the Middle East either.

In this situation, what can I do? I intend to claim asylum in a country that I can go to.

Comment: @NeanDerThal I have no idea what it means to be persecuted, but I am sure some people are driven to extremes in order to escape it.

Comment: Ordinarily, I would choose to delete the unkind comment above, but given that its response adds context, I am not going to. But I will ask @Nean Der Thal to be kinder in the future. The OP has ‘fessed up to the faking of the document, and that is tangential to his question. However, the persecution is still real

Comment: You can go to India and claim asylum. Much more closer to you cultrally and being gay is not illegal and if move to one of the big cities like Mumbai, you will be absolutely accepted and find gay bars, clubs, and very easy to connect with others.

Answer (score 5):

**You do not need an immigrant visa in order to claim asylum.** You only need a visitor visa. Once you are in a country you can make an asylum claim there. This is not illegal and will not count against you when you make your claim. Many refugees have arrived by this method, and it does not count against them.

If you believe you have a valid claim for asylum (and it certainly looks possible) then **you should attempt to get any visa you can for any country you would be OK with living in and then make a claim when you get there.**. If you have relatives in a country that is almost certainly the easiest way to go - make an application to visit them. Do not tell any lies or provide false documents during the application. If it is approved then when you get to the country and have been admitted tell the immigration official that you wish to make an asylum claim. I should warn you that normally in an asylum claim you need to provide actual evidence that you are or will be persecuted - not just saying "I'm gay and being gay is not allowed", but evidence that you personally have been persecuted or threated because of your sexual orientation. Here is a link about [making a refugee claim in Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/refugees/claim-protection-inside-canada/eligibility.html) as an example.

I write the above for anyone in this position who has not already received an immigration ban, so that they don't think they need to go down the road of immigrating. However your position will now be more difficult because of the ban. You need to declare it on any application you make if they ask about visa refusals (and they almost all will). Most Western countries will share information and know about your refusal, and that means getting any kind of visa is unlikely. You might try for a country that is not so closely allied with the UK but is still accepting of your lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

- You can of course attempt to enter a country under false premises and then request asylum. As relaxed points out in the comments, lies during the application *should* not be held against you during the asylum process, yet there are examples of officials who grasp at any reason to deny applications. Most Western countries pretend to uphold refugee conventions while they do their best to keep refugees from coming.
- You can try to **qualify** as an immigrant in one of the Western countries. Getting a STEM (science, technology, engineering, mathematics) degree would be a good first step, or possibly medical/nursing training, plus the language (since English-speaking countries are out for you). You mentioned European countries, there is e.g. the [Blue Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Card_(European_Union)) program. Of course interviews would be involved.
  This would take several years, but as I understand your posting what you are looking for are long-term prospects.

Comment: "Any lies on the way will be held against you during the asylum process": if that were to happen, it would be contrary to the refugee convention, which protects refugees from prosecution for violations they commit in reaching the country of refuge, including illegal entry.

Comment: @phoog, have you watched the asylum policies of Western countries lately? They do their very best to keep refugees out, while paying lip service to the conventions. The OP's claim of persecution would rest on his *self-identification* as homosexual, and people who lie to *enter* a country can be suspected of lying to *stay*.

Comment: The suggestion to try to *qualify*  for a visa seems very sensible to me. Having a sought-after skill might well tip the balance in the OP’s favour, and would make it much easier to find a good job/establish a new life. Also, do not assume that a UK refusal automatically means a denial from elsewhere. It certainly won’t help but it’s not insurmountable if you can qualify. Applying to Canada (disclosing the refusal of course) might be an option given its immigration levels plan https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/news/notices/supplementary-immigration-levels-2023-2025.html

Comment: The telling of untruths in a visa application process isn't viewed nearly as strictly in a refugee claims process as in a regular visa process. It's recognized that almost all persecuted individuals will have to bend some rules to get out of the country they are being persecuted by.

Comment: @o.m. Where exactly have you been “watching”? That's not how any of this works…

Comment: @Relaxed, in Germany. Where people who were thankfully in the opposition talked about shooting refugees at the border (Storch and Petry in 2016) and the processing of applications for Afghans who worked with the West goes at a dismal pace (in 2023). Meanwhile, Frontex turns a blind eye to illegal pushbacks. At the same time, the people currently in the government are talking about *Fachkräftemangel* and programs to recruit skilled immigrants. For migrants with the opportunity to get an university degree first, or even learn a trade, that looks like the *much* better option.

Comment: @o.m. OK, so zero insights about how the process actually works on the ground? There are massive violations, long delays, and general hostility, no arguments from me there, but it still doesn't mean that claims are just about “self-identification” or that “any lies [to enter the country] will be held against” the person making a claim.

Comment: In fact, that would be stupid as it would open the refusal to judicial review. If a protection officer were intent on violating the rules, they better find another pretext or [just pretend it's safe](https://www.politico.eu/article/gay-refugees-syria-lgbt-german-deportations-ignore-risks-asylum-seekers-face-at-home).

Comment: @Relaxed, my "insights" are people complaining about refusals, not people making decisions.

Comment: @Relaxed, https://www.proasyl.de/news/asyl-im-zeichen-des-regenbogens/

Comment: @o.m. I am familiar with these cases, have even heard crazier things, what's your point exactly? And if you have ever actually talked to people who faced refusals, did they tell you how the process went and the kind of questioning they faced? The link you just shared shows how detailed and intrusive it actually is, a far cry from what you are suggesting in your answer and definitely not focused on how a person entered the country or limited to their “self-identification”.

Comment: You will also note that, as I alluded to earlier, the decision mentioned at the top of the page is based on the fiction that the person would theoretically be safe in their country of origin, not on the reality of their sexual orientation, which tends to be easier to fight in court, as explained further down the page. You can also read [this article linked from the page you just shared](https://www.maenner.media/regional/gab/es-ist-ein-lotteriespiel/) to learn more about this.

Comment: @Relaxed, it is indeed possible to arrive as a tourist and then claim asylum. And if that is denied, one can appeal the decision in court. And for a LGBT individual from a country where this is persecuted, the application should be successful. But won't you agree that there is a significant gap between aspiration and reality when it comes to the EU asylum system? Deception during the visa application could make the claims appear as a *Nachfluchttatbestand*, as Germany puts it. I've edited the answer to point out that the way of entry *should not* matter.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the relevance of [the *Nachfluchttatbestände* concept](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/asylvfg_1992/__28.html). Here again, it's about whether the person actually was persecuted in their country of origin, not whether they committed a minor offense to cross the border. If anything, someone who lied to be able to leave because they were in imminent danger has a stronger case than someone who waited for the right occasion and subsequently decided they didn't want to go back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147556/discussion-between-relaxed-and-o-m).